# ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added: UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class BallHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject resBall;    
    [SerializeField] float detachDelay;    
    [SerializeField] float ResPawnDelay;    
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D pivot;    
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D Currentrb;    
    [SerializeField] SpringJoint2D currentJoint;    
    [SerializeField] float DelayedDUration;   

    Camera mainCam;    
    bool IsDrowning;    

    void Start()    
    {    
        mainCam = Camera.main;   

        SpawnNewBall();    
    }   

    void Update()   
    {    
        if(Currentrb == null) { return; }

        if (!Touchscreen.current.primaryTouch.press.isPressed)    
        {

            if(IsDrowning)    
            {    
                Launchball();    
            }

            IsDrowning = false;    
            return;    
        }    

        IsDrowning = true;    
        Currentrb.isKinematic = true;    

        Vector2 TouchPos = Touchscreen.current.primaryTouch.position.ReadValue();

        Vector3 worldPos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(TouchPos);    

        Currentrb.position = worldPos;    
    }    

    void SpawnNewBall()    
    {    
       GameObject balls = Instantiate(resBall, pivot.position, Quaternion.identity);    

        Currentrb = balls.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        currentJoint = balls.GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>();    

        currentJoint.connectedBody = pivot;    
    }
   
    void Launchball()    
    {    
        Currentrb.isKinematic = false;

        Currentrb = null;    

        Invoke(nameof(DetachBall), DelayedDUration);    
    }   

    void DetachBall()    
    {    
        currentJoint.enabled = false;    
        currentJoint = null;    

        Invoke(nameof(SpawnNewBall), ResPawnDelay);    
    }    
}
```

This is the script, during run time it works perfectly but when I build and run to export it over to my mobile, it gives the following error:

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
> Key: UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].TryInsert (TKey key, TValue value, System.Collections.Generic.InsertionBehavior behavior) (at `<eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>`:0)
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (TKey key, TValue value) (at `<eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>`:0)

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the script in question that causes the errors? Since it does not contain a dictonary

Comment: It looks like the dictionary is somewhere inside Unity's script compilation system - so you may have exposed an internal Unity bug. If this is indeed the script that causes the problem (delete it to check!), my suspicion would be the `Invoke` lines. `Invoke` is an outdated part of Unity, and has worse performance and maintainability than more modern additions: try replacing these calls with Coroutines and see if the problem persists.